# How tell by android programming when java/Android Bluetooth is doing l2ping response?

Tags: java, android, linux, bluetooth, l2cap

How can I programmaticaly perceive, in java on android, when my handset makes a response to a bluetooth l2ping?

For example in a hypothetical  moment, from linux I make the command:

```
l2ping 11:22:33:44:55..
```

then my handset responds to this.

I need, to capture this request for response on my handset by java programming.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! As a question and answer site we do not include greetings in our questions and responses. I have removed them for you and helped you with the English. However, we are not a free coding site. We do not give you code for the asking. You have to show what you have tried so far and then we help you get it working. So say what  you have tried so far bit using the [edit] button to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks Brian Tompset!!!